# Let's Encrypt Expiry Bot (certificate expiration notice)

Tags: lets-encrypt

I use Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 17.10 server with Apache HTTP server.
In crontab I have:

> 15 3 * * * /usr/bin/certbot renew

If I check expire date with:

> sudo certbot certificate

I get report for my two certificates with expire date 2018-03-18.
So far, so good.

But - I got an email from *expiry@letsencrypt.org* with notification that certificate for the same domain(s) will expire on *2018-01-16*.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps these are older certificates that you generated but have not revoked ? If the installed certificates have the correct date then you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Maybe. I will wait some days and see if there will be something wrong. It isn't production server, so this isn't dangerous :-)